# File upload using fetch instead of XHR

Tags: javascript

I am trying to upload an image using fetch instead of xhr. My request works successfully when I use xhr. My xhr request object is the following

```
var data = new FormData();
var photoObject = {
      uri: uriFromCameraRoll,
      type: 'image/jpeg',
      name: 'photo.jpg'
    };

data.append("photos", photoObject);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/");
xhr.send(data);
```

Now I am trying to use fetch like following

```
 fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/', {
     mode: 'no-cors',
     method: 'POST' ,
     body: data
 }).then(function(response) {
     console.log(response.status)
     console.log(response)
 })
```

But in my sever I am not receiving the file. Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

Comment: What is `body`?

Comment: Oops! it was a typo fixed it.

Comment: You might add an error function to your `then()`, or add a `catch()` depending on your Promise library. Then you can see what (if any) errors there are. You might also check the Network tab of your browser's developer tools to see if/how the two approaches diverge in what's being sent.

Comment: For simplicity, I removed some code. In server I am not receiving the file. I am receiving multer as uploader.